# Kafka paritioning with respect to timestamp to process only messages in parition of current hour parition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am working on a messaging system where messages are generated by user which have a time parameter.
I have a consumer which runs a job every hour and looks for messages that have time with current time and sends these messages.
I want to parition the topic "message" based on this time/timestamp in groups of one hour per parition, so that my consumer will only process one parition every hour instead of going through all messages every hour.

as of now i have a producer that will produce message in key value pair where key is the time with hour rounded off.

I have two questions :-

1. I can create 2-3 partitions by specifying in kafka settings but how can I have multiple patitions for every hour slot?
2. Should I rather create new topic for every hour and ask the consumer to only listen to the topic of the current hour?

example I am creating a topic named say "2020-7-23-10" which will contain all messages that need to be delivered between 10-11AM 23 July 2020. so I can just subscribe to this topic and process them.

or I can create a topic named "messages" and partition it based on the time and force my consumer to only process a particular patition.

Comment: Would setting the retention time of the topic to1 hour solve your problem?

Comment: no i am not setting retention time to 1 hour rather i am creating a topic named say "2020-7-23-10" which will contain all messages that need to be delivered between 10-11AM 23 July 2020. so i can just subscribe to this topic and process them.

Comment: okay, but that would mean you will end up having over 1500 topics already after about 10 weeks? Do you have control over the producer such that it could make use of partitions?

Comment: yeah thats what i thought exactly, i'm not sure if we can have dynamic partitions for a topic and whether we can control it via some specific APIs, i read the [kafka admin API to create new partition](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#createPartitions-java.util.Map-) but it will change the existing paritions as well and that will give undesired results for me